# probabilities and biostatistics

Tags: probability, statistics

assume that three industrial processes are independent, if the probability of successfully for 8 hours is 0.99 for process A, 0.95 for process B, and .80 for process C. then

*what is the probability that one or more successfully work for 8 hours ?

*what is the probability that one or more fails to work successfully for 8 hours ?

Comment: I guess the answer for the first one is 1-pr(y=0) which means 1-0.0001= 0.9999, but for the second one I'm not sure at all, any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- Find the probability for each process that it fails (e.g. for A, this is $1-0.99=0.01$)
- Find the probability that all three fail
- Find the probability that one or more successfully work
- Find the probability that all three successfully work
- Find the probability that one or more fail

Comment: ok, then for B its 0.05, and for C its 0.20. the probability that all fail is 0.01*0.05*0.20= 0.0001 and the probability that all three succeed is 0.99*0.95*0.80= 0.7524 so for one or more succeed is 1- 0.0001= 0.9999 , and the probability that one or more fail is 1-0.7524 ??? is that right, I'm not sure about the second one, is that right ?? @Henry

Comment: $0.2476$ looks correct to me